# 1040 Schedule A Un-Reimbursed Business Expense Reporting

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-1040

My question is about Form 1040 Schedule A Un-Reimbursed Business Expenses:

Can you Report Form 1040 Schedule A un-reimbursed business expenses that are greater than W-2 Income?

Comment: It's hard to imagine a scenario where this would make sense, maybe if you only worked somewhere a few days but bought a bunch of uniforms for the job. Most likely, no, but you'd need to add some context to your question for a good answer.  Also, don't use all caps.

Answer (score 1):

It would be unusual but it is possible that the expenses could be very high compared to your income.

The [IRS in pub 529](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p529#en_US_2016_publink100026912) explains the deduction.

> You can deduct only unreimbursed employee expenses that are:
>
> - Paid or incurred during your tax year,
> - For carrying on your trade or business of being an employee, and
> - Ordinary and necessary.
>
> An expense is ordinary if it is common and accepted in your trade,
>   business, or profession. An expense is necessary if it is appropriate
>   and helpful to your business. An expense doesn't have to be required
>   to be considered necessary.

The next part lists examples. I have cut the list down to highlight ones that could be large.

> You may be able to deduct the following items as unreimbursed employee
>   expenses.
>
> - Damages paid to a former employer for breach of an employment contract.
> - Job search expenses in your present occupation.
> - Legal fees related to your job.
> - Licenses and regulatory fees.
> - Malpractice insurance premiums.
> - Research expenses of a college professor.
> - Rural mail carriers' vehicle expenses.
> - Tools and supplies used in your work.
> - Work clothes and uniforms if required and not suitable for everyday use.
> - Work-related education.

If the term of employment was only part of the year, one or more of the these could dwarf your income for the year. Before deducting something that large be sure you can document it. I believe the IRS computers would flag the return and I wouldn't be surprised if they ask for additional proof.